# How to get the power series G(z^2) from G(z)

Tags: pari, pari-gp, power-series

I think it's an easy question, but I can't find how to do it correctly.

`substpol` works almost as I need, but doubles the polynomial degree.

For example, with :

> G(z)=1+2*z+3*z^2+O(z^5)

I got:

```
substpol(1+2*z^2+3*z^3 + O(z^5),z,z^2)
%20 = 1 + 2*z^4 + 3*z^6 + O(z^10)
```

but I would like to keep the result in O(z^5):

```
1 + 2*z^4 + O(z^5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally handle this situation by having a variable for the desired series length like `n` and then just tack on `+ O(x^n)`where appropriate. When I am super concerned about performance I will also reduce the length of the power series before substituting.

It is possible to get the precision of a series using `serprec`. The following function will substitute x for x^2 keeping the same precision:

```
f(s) = {subst(s, x, x^2) + O(x^serprec(s, x))}
f(1+2*x+3*x^2+O(x^5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the precision you want just by adding `+ O(z^5)` to your `substpol` expression.

```
> substpol(1+2*'z^2+3*'z^3 + O('z^5),'z,'z^2) + O('z^5)
1 + 2*z^4 + O(z^5)
```